# Get User Photo from Exchange server using PHP CURL

Tags: php, php-curl, exchange-server-2013

I am trying to get user profile picture located  in **Microsoft Exchange Server** [version 2013].

I can see the picture using below url [Example] :

https://companydomain.com/owa/service.svc/s/GetPersonaPhoto?email=user1%40companydomain.com&size=HR96x96&sc=1464941029314

**Requirement:**

To get all the company user's profile picture downloaded to a folder.

**What I have done so far?**

Written a Script using **Php CURL**

```
<?php 
    $user = 'user1@companydomain.com';
    $password = 'XXXXXXX';
    $fullurl="https://companydomain.com/owa/service.svc/s/GetPersonaPhoto?email=user1%40companydomain.com&size=HR96x96&sc=1464941029314";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$user:$password");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $fullurl);
    $returned = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
```

**Output:**
 A page containing: **Object moved to here.** as text and when I clicked on the link "here" it goes to login page  of Microsoft Outlook.

Please help me to get desired out put and let me know what I am missing.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could anyone please suggest me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you get redirected (301 or 302) at the URL you rovided. I can provide a solution, qhich provides you the "target"-URL which should be the needed Image.

```
    function get_web_page( $url ) 
{ 
    $options = array( 
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,     // return web page 
        CURLOPT_HEADER         => true,    // return headers 
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,     // follow redirects 
        CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",       // handle all encodings 
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "boss", // who am i 
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,     // set referer on redirect 
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,      // timeout on connect 
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,      // timeout on response 
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,       // stop after 10 redirects 
    ); 

    $ch      = curl_init( $url ); 
    curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options ); 
    $content = curl_exec( $ch ); 
    $err     = curl_errno( $ch ); 
    $errmsg  = curl_error( $ch ); 
    $header  = curl_getinfo( $ch ); 
    curl_close( $ch ); 

    //$header['errno']   = $err; 
   // $header['errmsg']  = $errmsg; 
    //$header['content'] = $content; 
    print($header[0]); 
    return $header; 
}  
$thisurl = "http://www.example.com/redirectfrom";
$myUrlInfo = get_web_page( $thisurl ); 
echo $myUrlInfo["url"];
```

you should get now http://www.example.com/redirectto